# Como fazer uma otimização com restrição de desigualdade?

Tags: r, matemática, otimização

Suponha que eu queira minimizar a seguinte função:

```
-(5-(x1-2)^2-2*(x2-1)^2)
s.a. x1+4*x2 < 3
```

Para problemas de otimização sem restrição posso usar o seguinte código.

```
fr <- function(x){
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  -(5-(x1-2)^2-2*(x2-1)^2)
}

optim(c(1,1),fr)
```

Como fazer a otimização com a restrição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou aprendendo português, mas este é uma solução sem inf explicita.

```
ui = c(-1, -4)
ci = c(-3)

fr <- function(x) {
    x1 = x[1]
    x2 = x[2]
    -(5-(x1-2)^2-2*(x2-1)^2)
}

constrOptim(c(1.6,.2), fr, ui=ui, ci=ci, method='Nelder-Mead')

$par
[1] 1.6668 0.3333

$value
[1] -4

$counts
function gradient 
     192       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$outer.iterations
[1] 3

$barrier.value
[1] -0.000
```

Answer (score 2):

Neste exemplo, você pode definir na função que, caso os valores ultrapassem a restrição, ela recebe valor infinito:

```
fr <- function(x){
  if(x[1]+4*x[2] > 3 ){value<-Inf}
  else{
    x1 <- x[1]
    x2 <- x[2]
    -(5-(x1-2)^2-2*(x2-1)^2)
  }
}
```

Resolvendo:

```
optim(c(1,0),fr)
$par
[1] 1.6666193 0.3333452

$value
[1] -4
```